# How to prove the following function is convex?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

I was working on a problem and it reduced to show that
$$f(a)=log\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{r}a^ix_i\Big)~~a>1, x_i>0$$
is convex. I have
$$f^{\prime \prime}(a)=\frac{\partial^2f(a)}{\partial a^2}=\frac{[\sum_{i=1}^{r}i(i-1)a^{i-2}x_i][\sum_{i=1}^{r}a^ix_i]-[\sum_{i=1}^{r}ia^{i-1}x_i]^2}{[\sum_{i=1}^{r}a^ix_i]^2}.$$
Can you show that $f^{\prime \prime}(a)>0$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a convex function. For $r=1$ and $x=1$ you get $f(a) = \log(a)$ which is clearly non-convex.